# convertion of ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> type to int

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Stored proc return as `ObjectResult<Nullable<int>>` using Entity frame work and want to convert this to int type
or how to check this value with another integer value

Answer (score 4):

You have to loop over the `ObjectResult<T>` or use `ObjectResult<T>.ElementAt()` to retrieve individual elements. Then you can access the `int` values:

```
ObjectResult<Nullable<int>> queryResult = query.Execute(...);

foreach (Nullable<int> result in queryResult)
   Console.WriteLine("{0}", result.Value);
```

You can check if a value is available using `ObjectResult<T>.HasValue`

Answer (score 2):

First check if the nullable object has a value - if so then get its value

```
if (someNullableIntObject.HasValue)
{
   int intValue = someNullabelObject.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:

```
Nullable<int> myValue = myDb.MY_STORED_PROCEDURE().FirstOrDefault();
int a = myValue.Value;
```